# Cannot connect to SQL Server database using Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, timeout, ssms, windows-authentication, localdb

I can't connect locally to any SQL Server database using Windows Authentication and it doesn't matter if it's LocalDB or Express edition. My operating system is Windows 7 Professional 64-bit. When I try to connect in Visual Studio Community 2015 or SQL Server Management Studio, it only shows error message **Connection timeout expired** without any helpful details. I don't have any problem with connection using my SQL Server administrator account in VS and SSMS.

I tried every solution which I could find, e.g.:

- I removed, recreated and started LocalDB instances,
- I installed all updates,
- I turned off firewall,
- I installed SQL Server Data Tools feature in Visual Studio,
- I restarted all Windows services related to SQL Server,
- I added all possible permissions to my Windows account in SQL configuration,
- I run Visual Studio and SSMS as Administrator,
- I installed older version of Visual Studio (but it doesn't matter, because SSMS gives me exactly the same error message).

I also found that this error may be caused by having not enough resources, but in my case it's not the reason.

Finally I formatted my HDD and installed new OS (the same Windows version). I installed only Visual Studio Community 2015 with all features and updates and I was still getting the same error message.

I didn't have any problem with connection using my PC at work and I didn't have to do anything special. Installing Visual Studio was all I had to do. I opened the same Visual Studio project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs when computer's name is a number. Windows 7 doesn't allow to change computer's name to one that contains only digits, but Windows 7 installer allows to set number as computer's name and it doesn't show any warning about that while using operating system.
Changing computer's name and restarting OS is a solution.

Comment: I always set number as computer's name. I had this problem for last few months and I didn't find solution to that problem anywhere in the internet, so I answered my own question. In 2 days I will accept that answer or if someone else can be more specific (e.g. add some information from SQL Server documentation or link to Microsoft FAQ related to that problem), I will accept her/his answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following steps :**

- Open the Windows Run menu using the WIN + R shortcut key and then type in `sysdm.cpl` into the window and hit enter.
- you’ll see a [dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXhbr.jpg), which should say System Properties. Make sure you are on the Computer Name tab.
- Click on the “Change” button to rename the computer, which will pop up this [dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CR1E8.jpg).
- Now you can finally change the name of the computer. You could also change the name of the workgroup to something more descriptive as well. You’ll have to reboot after you make this change.

**After that try to connect to SQL Server database using Windows Authentication.**